# Resharper Test Runner steals focus

Tags: resharper

Though one: whenever I run a test with R# using a hotkey (CTRL+U, CTRL+R), the runner window get focus. It's ruining my performance.

Does anyone have any clue as to what I did to cause that? IIRC, this wasn't so until yesterday.

Comment: This has annoyed me for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked out how to stop this from happening, but the following shortcuts do help:

- Ctrl+Tab (Navigate between files opened in the editor, and tool windows.)
- Shift+Esc (Close current tool/window.)